# How can I use array from mysql in mongodb query?

Tags: php, mysql, mongodb

I search mysql db and get the result into a php array ($ID).

```
 $ID=array();

 while($Rlist=mysql_fetch_array($query_result)){
            $ID[] = $Rlist['ids'];                  
 }
```

I like to use the array of IDs in a mongodb query.

```
 $list=$collection->find(array("id"=>array('$in'=>[$ID])), array("title" => 1, "detail" => 1, "logo" => 1  ))->limit(50);
```

As you may quess, I'm not succesfull.  How can we solve this problem?

UPDATE:
The problem here, php array format is:

```
$ID="1,2,3,4";
```

but mongodb needs a format like:

```
$ID='1','2','3','4';
```

UPDATE 
var_dump($ID);

array(20) { [0]=> string(3) "502" [1]=> string(4) "1643" [2]=> string(4) "3342" [3]=> string(4) "6948" [4]=> string(4) "8582" [5]=> string(4) "9420" [6]=> string(5) "10293" [7]=> string(5) "11014" [8]=> string(5) "12331" [9]=> string(5) "13874" [10]=> string(5) "19430" [11]=> string(5) "48789" [12]=> string(5) "67190" [13]=> string(6) "191315" [14]=> string(6) "293354" [15]=> string(6) "390314" [16]=> string(6) "500715" [17]=> string(6) "504151" [18]=> string(6) "742853" [19]=> string(6) "913465" }

Comment: Assuming that `$ID` is now an array of items you wish to match you can just take out the `[]` around the `$ID` variable.

Comment: @Sammaye: If I remove [] around $ID mongodb throws error.

Comment: Can you var_dump `$ID` for us?

Comment: Why don't you use `array_push($ID, $Rlist['ids'])` instead of `$ID[] = $Rlist['ids'];` http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php

Comment: hmm, that var_dump should work, what is the error?

Comment: @Sammaye: Sorry, I realized there was a mistyping that throws error. I corrected it. Anyway, Array problem remains same.. Instead of array, if I write ['1','2','3','4'] manually, it works. But when I use php array, mongodb query do nothing

Comment: @Sammaye: Thanks, I solved the problem. Took the [] out after correcting error. Worked now.